# Logback: Multiple Property Sources

Tags: logback

I want to do something like:

```
<insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:comp/env/conf/app-log-path" as="logPath" />
<if test='!isDefined("logPath") &amp;&amp; isDefined("catalina.home")'>
  <then>
    <property name="logPath" value="${catalina.home}/logs/" />
  </then>
</if>
<appender name="ROLLING_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${logPath:-logs/}myapp.log</file>
</appender>
```

that is, allow a JNDI property to be sent in to my logging configuration, and if that is not found then try using catalina.home, and if that is not found then use a default value.  Is this possible?  It seems to me that is should be, but the  never seems to take effect, maybe properties can't be updated in this manner?  The documentation (chapter 3 of the manual) makes the property substituton seem quite powerful, but I just can't seem to get it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got an old or incorrect demo.  Immediately after posting this, I realized that the attribute is condition=""  instead of  test="".

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure where I got the use of the attribute @test from, but when I went back over some other example (for what was the 3rd time) I finally noticed the difference.  I did need the Janio lib, but I already had that.  In general the logback docs are pretty nice, but some of the more advanced stuff could use a few more 'step by step' style how-tos.